Date format in xlsx file using Swift Excel
I am using swift excel for writing a large xlsx file which has multiple date types, like  String, Numbers and Date.
I am able to write string and number using following code
But when i write a date using following code, it is also written as string only.
Please help me on the same
Code for writing excel
Code for finding the data type

Your code for writing excel is wrong, a date value looks different in the XML:  45404 (which is today; 2024-4-22)
